# NGINX listing is correctly configured to accept HTTP traffic, but reciving 'The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port' 400 error

Tags: nginx, proxy, https, http

We have some IIS sites hosted locally on some servers which we are upgrading. These sites need to be accessed by both HTTP and HTTPS, both on the new and old servers. We have assigned unique port numbers to these services so that there is no port number conflicts. We are using DNS to direct any calls for these sites to the NGINX reverse proxy, which then directs it to the appropriate server.

I am attempting to access one of our sites via 'http://[site]:8080', however it is giving me a 400 error "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port". When I change the URL to go to http**s**://[site]:8080, it works fine and I can access the site correctly, but we don't want to use HTTPS here, as we have secure traffic using a different port.

I copied the config below from an existing entry within NGNIX and made some changes to point it to the correct server. The SSL information shown was already existing within the config, so I commented them out, but it still has the same behaviour. I also added the 'ssl off' tag, but that also didn't seem to have any affect. The only other change I made was removing `ssl` from the `listen` line

```
server {
   listen 8080;
   server_name [SITE];
   ssl off;
   #ssl_certificate  [certificate path];
   #ssl_certificate_key  [certificate key];
   #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   location / {
       #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       #proxy_ssl_certificate [certificate];
       #proxy_ssl_certificate_key [key];
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://[server name]:8080;
       proxy_set_header        Host $host;
       #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       #proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
}
```

I have made a post about this elsewhere, where it was suggested that I should remove the lines I commented out above, however that dosen't seem to have any impact, and I'm still getting the same error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably there is another config with this port and ssl enabled

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thank you! I thought that it only read the listing which applied to the specific service, but removing 'ssl' from the rest of the unsecured listings worked!